# PHP Array Validation

Tags: php, aws-cli

We are building a monitoring tool use PHP and  Mysql for the servers hosted in AWS, we collect the data calling the AWS CLI from PHP, the requirement is that only when there is a data change then update the tables else do not update the table ,so in order to validate where the data is changed we are using the md5(serialize) function and storing the checksum value in a table and every time we call the awscli the output of the command is validated with the stored checksum value if the value is different then it will update the database else it will not update the database e.g, so can I request your advice and recommendation on this approach or if there are any better solution than the current one.

***Code***

```
$command = "/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters Name=tag:cloud-environment,Values='XXXX'";
exec($command, $output, $status);
foreach($output as $op) {
   $checksum = md5(serialize($output));
    if(!empty($output) and $checksum != XXX) {
       update table
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example how `$output` looks like?

Comment: The output of the aws cli is an array similar as below ***BAU-TST     WSERV1   i-12345678     r4.8xlarge      eu-east-1c      ami-a123456    2018-05-28 07:29:27 UTC None    2018-12-12T06:22:28.000Z       None     UAT-DB-1        stopped User initiated (2019-04-04 15:43:36 GMT)
BAU-MOK     WSERV2   i-12345876     r4.8xlarge      eu-east-1c      ami-a123456    2018-05-28 07:29:27 UTC None    2018-12-12T06:22:28.000Z       None     MOK-DB-1        stopped User initiated (2019-04-04 15:43:36 GMT)***

Comment: Each item in the `$output` array is already a string, is there a reason why you serialize before you hash it? I think your code example, especially the loop part has some errors that you should correct first, as it is not really clear what you want to do there

Comment: PHP does not allow to hash an array, hence we have to serialize the array before hashing.

Comment: Yes but you put a foreach loop around it, that makes only sense when you want to hash each individual line, so I thought you just messed up `$output` and `$op`, you understand?

Comment: Hi Benni, Sorry, the line "$checksum = md5(serialize($output));" should be before the for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in one line

```
$command = "/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters Name=tag:cloud-environment,Values='XXXX' | md5sum";
```